# How to avoid the registration of box.once('init', function ...) when the init function fails?

Tags: lua, tarantool

I want to implement an **init** function under **box.once()** to be executed only once in Tarantool, however, this is useful to me only if **init** has been executed successfully.

**Question**: How can I make the "*onceinit*" record valid only if init has run successfully??

**To reproduce the case**:

The following code of the **init** function fails because there is no **create_space_BAD** function, however, when scanning the schema it is registered as executed.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

The code:

```
local function start()
    box.cfg{}
    box.once('init', function()
        if not pcall(box.schema.create_space_BAD, 'myspace') then
            print('ERROR: create_space_BAD NOT EXIST')
            return false
        end
   ...
   end)
end
```

Explore schema:

```sh
tarantool> box.space._schema:select{}
---
- - ['cluster', '1cb21086-51a3-46fb-900e-1983609fc396']
  - ['max_id', 511]
  - ['onceinit']
  - ['version', 1, 10, 2]
...
```

Comment: Ilya K. from Tarantool Telegram Group answered me: Using box.space._schema:delete('onceinit') in case the init function fails should solve this problem

Comment: was about to say the same: just delete it manually. You can easily do that using `xpcall`, by the way :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem can be solved using box.space._schema:delete('onceinit') to explicitly deregister your init function.

Like:

```
local function start()
  box.cfg{}
  box.once('init', function()
      if not pcall(box.schema.create_space_BAD, 'myspace') then
    print('ERROR: create_space_BAD NOT EXIST')
    box.space._schema:delete('onceinit')
    return false
      end
        end)
end
```

Then you will see:

```
tarantool> box.space._schema:select{}
---
- - ['cluster', 'd6a9d97b-3a3f-4f69-8d1a-65ae5a073c16']
  - ['max_id', 511]
  - ['version', 2, 3, 1]
...
```

For more details see https://www.tarantool.io/en/doc/1.10/reference/reference_lua/box_once/

Answer (score 1):

Note that approach with `box.space._schema:delete` won't work if you create several spaces/indexes. The recommended way is to use `if_not_exists` option instead of `box.once`.

See https://www.tarantool.io/en/doc/2.3/reference/reference_lua/box_schema/#box-schema-space-create

and

https://www.tarantool.io/en/doc/2.3/reference/reference_lua/box_space/#box-space-create-index